# Is it possible to synthesize a benzene ring with every carbon on the ring substituted?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

We recently began covering aromatic electrophillic substitution in my first year organic chemistry course, and we've been discussing the nature of certain functional groups being activating $(\ce{-OH},$ $\ce{-OCH3},$ $\ce{-NH2})$ or deactivating $(\ce{-SO3H},$ $\ce{-NO2}).$

We haven't learned how to do everything obviously, so this probably why I can't answer this question myself, but we've learned how to add nitro groups, sulfonic acid groups, alkyl and acyl groups, and halogens.

In any case, is there way out there in the world of organic chemistry to create a benzene ring with every single carbon substituted?

Comment: Hexachlorobenzene and hexafluorobenzene exist

Comment: There are simply too many examples. You might want to narrow down your question, e.g. by specifying the exact groups of interest or adding extra restraints such as uniqueness of each group or their order.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylbenzol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellitic_acid

Comment: The interesting one is also a mellitic anhydride, that is formally a carbon oxide C12O9 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellitic_anhydride

Comment: I don't really see why this is too broad; it's a simple yes/no question to which the answer is "yes", which is maybe not a super interesting answer, but it's not broad. OP isn't asking anybody to enumerate all the possible compounds or methods.